# CSS list style issue

Tags: jquery, css, html

Please help me to solve issue with css list-style. I am trying to remove circles that appear before the link. I have tried almost everything, but no success. Also there are strange borders which appear before the link. here is live website http://media-grozny.ru/services/

Comment: How about the code? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Put the required code to generate the bug here.  this question cannot be reused or help others.

Comment: This style is solve your problem 

    .color-list li:before {
        display: none !important;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    }
```

As in the example:

```css
li {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> test </li>
  <li> test </li>
  <li> test </li>

</ul>
```

Comment: I have already tried that but didnt work

Comment: Try    list-style-type: none !important;